# Makefile dependency that doesn't trigger recompilation?

Tags: makefile

I want to declare non-file targets in a makefile that

- Can be used as dependency by file targets without causing those to always be rebuilt, and
- Execute commands if and only if some dependency has been rebuilt.

In the simplest case, such a target would simply serve as a "name" for a list of targets.

However, any file-target that depends on such a "name" target will always be rebuilt, e.g.:

```
>> make --debug
   File 'PREPROCESS' does not exist.
  Must remake target 'PREPROCESS'.
  Successfully remade target file 'PREPROCESS'.
 Prerequisite 'PREPROCESS' of target 'config.ini' does not exist.
Must remake target 'config.ini'.
```

The only workaround I can think of is creating a dummy file with `touch $@`, but that would clutter the source directory with unwanted files.

Usually, makefiles solve this by defining a group of files as a variable at the beginning of the file and use that variable in dependency lists, but that doesn't allow to execute code at the end of such a phase.

Is there some better way to name a group of dependencies?

### Example makefile

```
config.ini: PREPROCESS
    touch $@

.PHONY: clean

PREPROCESS: preproc.ini preproc.x
    : ./print_preprocess_report

preproc.ini:
    touch $@

preproc.x:
    touch $@

clean:
    rm -f preproc.ini preproc.x config.ini
```

Comment: Even for [phony targets](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html#Phony-Targets) their dependencies should not be rebuilt unless they changed.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes but the OP wants a target that "_can be used as dependency by file targets without causing those to always be rebuilt_". This cannot be a phony target.

Comment: But if both preproc.ini and preproc.x change the command should only be executed once?

Comment: @Markus Preferably yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to declare non-file targets in a makefile that
>
> - Can be used as dependency by file targets without causing those to always be rebuilt, and
> - Execute commands if and only if some dependency has been rebuilt.

This combination of characteristics is not supported by standard `make`.  If you define a prerequisite for a target and that prerequisite initially does not exist, then `make` *will* consider the target to be out of date.  If the rule for that prerequisite does not actually create it (and it doesn't already exist) then the original target will always be considered out of date.

If you're willing to rely specifically on GNU `make` then you can get a little farther.  GNU `make` has the concept of *order-only prerequisites*, which satisfy your first objective and the "if" part of your second objective, but not the "only if".  When faced with a prerequisite that does not exist and a rule providing a recipe for that target, GNU `make`, too, will execute the recipe.  There is no way to express the idea of a target that is out of date only if its prerequisites are out of date.  But perhaps that's good enough.  It might look like this:

```
DEPS = preproc.ini preproc.x

# order-only prerequisites are separated from standard ones by a pipe symbol (|)
# ... and you probably do need regular prerequisites too, else the target is out of date
# only if it does not already exist at all.
config.ini: $(DEPS) | PREPROCESS
    touch $@

# marking PREPROCESS phony is appropriate, but it solves a different problem
.PHONY: clean PREPROCESS

PREPROCESS: $(DEPS)
    : ./print_preprocess_report

preproc.ini:
    touch $@

preproc.x:
    touch $@

clean:
    rm -f preproc.ini preproc.x config.ini
```

If you want fully to achieve your two bullet points, then it the "non-file targets" part of your requirement needs to give way.  This is basically the workaround presented in the question, though it might be the case that it makes as much sense to have the target create a *bona fide* build result instead of a dummy file.  In the example makefile, for instance, the rule for `PREPROCESS` could write the report not only to the standard output, but also to a file named `PREPROCESS`.  That does not require use of order-only prerequisites, by the way, so it is portable.

Comment: With order-only prerequisites `config.ini` will not be rebuilt if it is out of date but all its order-only prerequisites exist. Not sure it is the OP wants.

Comment: Well, @RenaudPacalet, that is how I interpret the OP's criterion that the target "Can be used as dependency by file targets without causing those to always be rebuilt".  Do you read the requirement differently?

Comment: I do not really know how it should be interpreted but considering the only working solution proposed by the OP: empty dummy files (except that they pollute the source tree) one possibility could be that `config.ini` depends (directly or not) on `preproc.ini` and `preproc.x` and that it should be rebuilt if it is out of date with respect to these files...

Comment: After some consideration, @RenaudPacalet, I decided that a slightly fuller treatment is indeed warranted.  It goes beyond what the OP actually asked, but it addresses what they most likely want.  (Updated)

Comment: Interesting. I like the order-only idea but `PREPROCESS` being phony, the `print_preprocess_report` will always be executed, even if `preproc.ini` and `preproc.x` are up to date. Something else is needed to prevent this.

Comment: Yes, @RenaudPacalet, it is expressly stated in this answer that the full list of requirements expressed by the OP cannot be satisfied, neither via a POSIX-conforming `make` in general nor via GNU `make` specifically.  That appears to have been your conclusion as well.

Answer (score 2):

There may be a way but all ideas I have are probably uselessly complicated, difficult to understand and maintain.

Honestly, designing a monster Makefile just to avoid creating empty timestamp files looks overkill to me (but look at the last part of this answer). Do you know that you can create these files anywhere, for instance in a sub-directory of your source tree for easier cleaning, or even out of it? Example:

```
# separate subdir of source tree
TAGSDIR    := .tags
# out of tree directory
# TAGSDIR  := /tmp/.tags
PREPROCESS := preproc.ini preproc.x

config.ini: $(TAGSDIR)/preprocess
    touch $@

.PHONY: clean

$(TAGSDIR)/preprocess: $(PREPROCESS)
    : ./print_preprocess_report
    mkdir -p $(@D)
    touch $@

preproc.ini:
    touch $@

preproc.x:
    touch $@

clean:
    rm -f $(PREPROCESS) config.ini $(TAGSDIR)
```

OK, now if you really insist on this, here is a complicated solution. It uses an empty dummy file but in a temporary location (`/tmp`) in order to not pollute your source tree. As we cannot expect it to be there when we run make, we will create it when the Makefile is parsed by make and we will give it the last modification time of the most recent `PREPROCESS` target. This should work as you expect:

```
PREPROCESS := preproc.ini preproc.x
PP         := $(wildcard $(PREPROCESS))
TAGFILE    := /tmp/preprocess
ifneq ($(PP),)
NAMESTIMES := $(shell stat -c"%n %Y" $(PP) | sort -rnk2)
MOSTRECENT := $(firstword $(NAMESTIMES))
$(shell touch --reference=$(MOSTRECENT) $(TAGFILE))
endif

config.ini: $(TAGFILE)
    touch $@

$(TAGFILE): $(PREPROCESS)
    : ./print_preprocess_report
    @touch $@

.PHONY: clean

preproc.ini: foo
    touch $@

preproc.x: bar
    touch $@

clean:
    rm -f $(PREPROCESS) config.ini $(TAGFILE)
```

Note that I added prerequisites to `preproc.ini` and `preproc.x` to demonstrate what happens if they are rebuilt while they existed already. Demo:

```
$ touch foo bar
$ make
touch preproc.ini
touch preproc.x
: ./print_preprocess_report
touch config.ini
$ touch foo bar
$ make
touch preproc.ini
touch preproc.x
: ./print_preprocess_report
touch config.ini
```